# Console does not appear on Robot

Tags: java

I'm creating a utility console that does some basic key pressing for me.
But for some reason, the console view does not appear, but it is still doing its job.

This is the piece of code:

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    int x =1;

    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        delay();
        System.out.println("Processing Bot...");
    }

    do{
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        delay();
        System.out.println("Key Active : Tab");

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_1);
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            delay();
        }
        System.out.println("Key Active : 1");

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            delay();
        }
        System.out.println("Key Active : 2");

    }while(x!=0);
    ...

}
```

How do I make the console appear, because it is hard closing the apps from here

[image]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit:
This is the delay code :

```
public static void delay(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean 'make the console appear'? What shortcut are you using to open said console?

Comment: I mean , take a look at the "Processing bot...". There is no console that appears print that line, but the system still runs.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "no console appears print that line, but the system still runs"?

Comment: Usually when u do `System.out.println("Key Active : 1");`. There will be a `cmd` like console which prints out the line , in my case it doesnt, but it still does the key press and key release thing which i implemented on the code.

Comment: Oh, you mean the terminal window. But the code works fine for me. Maybe you could show some more of your code to help us better understand.

Comment: What's `delay()`?

Comment: Also, post the code of your delay method. I feel if it's not sufficiently long enough, then there could be some problems.

Comment: That is actually the whole code, the only part i left is the `catch` and `delay()` only do some `Thread.sleep()`. And yes the code works fine but the problem is the terminal wont show up.